# IntelliJ structural search regex questions

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea, structural-search, inspections

I need to match variables that start with a lowercase letter and don't end in an underscore.

I have these three fields:

```
private String shouldFlag;
private String shouldntFlag_;
private String SHOULDNTFLAG;
```

With this pattern inverted:
`^[a-z].*_$`

Used with for fieldname in the following template:

```
class $Class$ { 
  $FieldType$ $FieldName$ = $Init$;
}
```

The problem is that `SHOULDNTFLAG` is still flagged. I tried using `^[a-z].*_$|^[A-Z].*$`, but that did  not match anything, let alone just `shouldFlag`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your variable names can only contain ASCII letters and digits plus the underscore, I would go with

```
\b[a-z]\w*\b(?<!_)
```

EDIT: ...and, as @Stefan pointed out, you need to select the "case-sensitive" option.

Comment: This seems to accept SHOULDNTFLAG in Intelli-J. It looks like it's treating the [a-z] character class as [a-zA-Z]

Comment: You need to explicitly check "case sensitive" in the SSR.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I've never actually used that feature.  I always expect regex-powered search tools--especially in IDE's and programmers' editors--to be case-sensitive by default, but they keep surprising me. :/

Comment: I think Intelli-J's SSR is just a bit broken. I've encountered a number of issues already, and it turns out I can't even use this due to its unpredictable behavior. Hopefully IntelliJ 10 will hammer out these bugs.

Comment: If you found bugs, please submit them at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA, otherwise they will not be fixed in IDEA 10.